# How to reduce a categorical variable in a logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I've created a logistic regression formula regarding mpg for various makes and models of cars.
One variable "origin" was integer with : 1=American, 2=German, 3=Japanese.
I converted it to

```
origin.factor <- factor(origin,labels=c("American", "German", "Japanese")
> head(origin.factor)
[1] American American American American American
[6] American
Levels: American German Japanese
```

First, it was suggested I convert "origin" to factor using as.factor and relabel, but I did not see how to pass the label=c("American", "German", "Japanese") with as.factor.
Any ideas?

Next, initial Logistic model with all variables yielded this output (sorry the columns are not aligning in this post, but the last column is the p-values in bold for each variable):

```
> auto.mpg.logistic <- glm(mpg.binary~cylinders + displacement + horsepower + weight + acceleration + year + origin.factor, family="binomial")
> summary(auto.mpg.logistic)

Call:
glm(formula = mpg.binary ~ cylinders + displacement + horsepower + 
    weight + acceleration + year + origin.factor, family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-2.44937  -0.08809   0.00577   0.19315   3.03363  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -19.450793   5.956353  -3.266  **0.00109** ** 

cylinders              -0.264169   0.439645  -0.601  **0.54793**   
displacement            0.015568   0.013658   1.140  **0.25434**   
horsepower             -0.043081   0.024621  -1.750  **0.08017** .  
weight                 -0.005762   0.001376  -4.187 **2.83e-05** ***

acceleration            0.012939   0.142921   0.091  **0.92786**    
year                    0.495635   0.086155   5.753 **8.78e-09** ***

origin.factorGerman     1.971277   0.785573   2.509  **0.01210** * 
 
origin.factorJapanese   1.102741   0.713768   1.545  **0.12236**    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

next I proceeded to remove the variables where the p-value is > 0.05 level of significance to arrive at the following output:

```
> auto.mpg.logistic <- glm(mpg.binary~ horsepower + weight + year + origin.factor, family="binomial")
> summary(auto.mpg.logistic)

Call:
glm(formula = mpg.binary ~ horsepower + weight + year + origin.factor, 
    family = "binomial")

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.2675  -0.0943   0.0080   0.2007   3.2653  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -18.240055   4.912407  -3.713 0.000205 ***

horsepower             -0.042209   0.016441  -2.567 0.010251 * 
 
weight                 -0.004607   0.000734  -6.276 3.47e-10 ***

year                    0.457663   0.075997   6.022 1.72e-09 ***

origin.factorGerman     1.335225   0.529879   2.520 0.011740 *  

origin.factorJapanese   0.628677   0.580123   1.084 0.278500    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Now the only variable that is still above the 0.05 level of significance is origin.factorJapanese

So the question is, can I somehow remove just origin.factorJapanese and leave in Origin.factorGerman since it is significant?

Or is the appropriate action to remove origin.factor which will eliminate all aspects of this categorical variable from my logistic model (this seems like my only option...)?

I'm new to R and primarily use base R functions as per our class assignments so please consider that in your answers.
Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1):

This is really about statistics more than it is about R. You have a model which has a bunch of continuous explanatory variables (`horsepower`, `weight`, `year`), and a single factor `origin.factor`. The model you are fitting is a *parallel lines* model. That is, for each  *level* of `origin.factor` you are fitting a hyper-plane (but just think about it as a line if it helps) with a different intercept for each country of origin.

R uses the `Intercept` to fit the base level of your factor, and the remaining factor levels are really the difference between the base level and the level. Therefore what the regression summary table is telling you that German cars are different from American cars (`American` is the base because it comes first alphabetically which is how R handles factors by default), but Japanese cars are not. Note it tells you **nothing** about the difference between German and Japanese cars.

So, you have some evidence that there are differences between the levels of the factors, but not all of them. You really don't want to try and fit the model without the Japanese level in there (well you might but not for the reasons you think).

Comment: Hi James.  Thank you for the reply.  Your answer does make sense and confirms my thought that the Origin variable with level = American is included in the base level estimate for the regression model.  And if I remove Origin, I remove the "American" component from the base level in addition to German and Japanese, which would not be desirable.  So, how do I justify leaving Origin.factorJapanese in the model when its p-value is so high above the alpha?

Comment: Think about it as drawing a set of parallel lines on a graph. Some of these will be far enough apart to be "statistically significant" - i.e. we really believe there is sufficient evidence to say the intercepts are different. The fact that the Japanese one is not significantly different from the American means that we don't have enough evidence to show they are different, and so can be regarded as the same. You could recode Japanese as American and refit the model if you're really concerned, but I wouldn't bother.